# START/STOP button that stores it's value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to create a Start/Stop (single button) to send record commands to a camera.

The commands are sent through command pipe, written in php.

The button should store it's value. This way, when the page is refreshed, it'd remember the last value.

For exemple:

I hit the button "Start" for the first time.
It'll send command to start recording and change itself to "Stop".
If I reload the page, i'd find a "Stop" button that would send command to stop recording. When clicked, it'd go back to default state, which is "Start".

Could someone help, please?

Here is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="javaScript:startstopRecording()" id="startButton">
```

JS

```
var recording = null;
function init(){

}

startstopRecording = function(){
    if(recording != null){
        stop();
    } else {
        start();

    }
    change();
}

function start(){
}

change = function(){
var elem = document.getElementById("startButton");
if (elem.value=="Stop") elem.value = "Start";
else elem.value = "Stop";
}

stop = function(){
    recording = null;
}
window.onload = recording;
```

Comment: Why did you tag java?

Comment: Sorry. It was supposed to be javascript.

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Comment: What more information would be needed for help? Thx

Comment: @AndréLuís What do you mean by recording? Just a rectangle with a video output? Or do you want to save it in a storage on a server? Maybe online translation? What's your goal?

Comment: @VladimirVlasov It's a security camera, written in python and running on Debian that streams the video output to a php webpage. You can send commands from the webpage to the camera through a command pipe. For example, send_cmd("ca 1"); would start recording and send_cmd("ca 0"); would stop.

Comment: @AndréLuís So, what you really want is to manipulate your camera with an HTML page, right? Do you need the video output on the page as well? And this python service, is it your own product? Or is it a 3rd-party one?

Comment: 3rd party open source. Raspimjpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin.
The stored data is saved across browser sessions. localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends that is when the page is closed.

You should set an item in localStorage after pressing the button:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("recording", 1); // or 0
```

And you can get the latest value of status like this:

```
var recording = window.localStorage.getItem('recording');
```

Here is more help for you to understand it:

```
var recording = window.localStorage.getItem('recording');
startstopRecording = function(){
    if(recording == 1) {
        stop();
    } else {
        start();
    }
    change();
}

function start() {
    //start recording
    window.localStorage.setItem("recording", 1);
}

function stop()  {
    //stop recording
    window.localStorage.setItem("recording", 0);
}
change();
```

Comment: I'm not being lazy, just too stupid: could you exemplify your suggestion on what I have so far? Thanks!

Comment: Hosted a SimpleHTTPServer and the button seems to be stuck at Start (it doesn't change to Stop).

Comment: Oh! It was missing the change function. However, I added two more commands to each function window.alert("recording"); and window.alert("stoped recording");. It always show the first alert (recording), which was placed in the function start.

Comment: This is your solution method, try to fix the code yourself. use the link, have some research...

Comment: I'll keep trying and let you know. So far, the button is changing itself, but still sending only 1 kind of alert. Thx!

Comment: I tried to debug the code myself.

https://jsfiddle.net/andreluisos/uaxr8mz5/


Shouldn't this make the button called "Stop" when the page is loaded? It isn't.

Comment: I modified the jsfiddle, look at it again: https://jsfiddle.net/uaxr8mz5/4/

Comment: That was extremely helpful. Thanks!